# When did Star Trek stop using models?

Tags: star-trek

When did Star Trek stop using (real) models for exterior shots of spacecraft?  I recall that there was an actual DS9 model and NCC-1701-D that were up for sale, but I don't think there was a Voyager.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The special effects team stopped making new models in the later seasons of Voyager and never resumed.

[*Enterprise* was the first series to have absolutely no models.](http://www.sci-fi-online.com/Features/03-05-12_Enterprise.htm)  To provide a quote from that article:

> With Enterprise there are no models, not even a visual model for the
>   ship except for a paper version created in order to envision how
>   certain shots might work. "I guess in a sense it is a precedent,
>   **Voyager being the last one to use practicals**, even though they went
>   away from them in the end," notes Bonchune. "This show is all CGI. We
>   built a CG version of a real ship, with the difference being in the
>   small details. You can sit on the hull on certain parts of the ship.
>   You can keep a camera flying in so you can see writing on small panels
>   on the cargo doors. If it was a filming miniature, you could never do
>   that."

(emphasis mine)

CGI became good enough for cheap enough that it could be used instead.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Voyager) says that Voyager stopped using models in Season 3.

> Voyager was also the first Star Trek TV show to eliminate the use of
>   models for exterior space shots and exclusively use computer-generated
>   imagery (CGI) instead. Other television shows such as seaQuest DSV and
>   Babylon 5 had previously used CGI exclusively to avoid the huge
>   expense of models, but the Star Trek television department continued
>   using models, because they felt models provided better realism. Amblin
>   Imaging won an Emmy for the opening CGI title visuals, but the weekly
>   episode exteriors were captured using hand-built miniatures of the
>   Voyager, shuttlecraft, and other ships. That changed when Star Trek:
>   Voyager went fully CGI for certain types of shots midway through
>   Season 3 (late 1996).[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqB2Q.jpg) Paramount obtained an exclusive contract with
>   Foundation Imaging, the studio responsible for special effects during
>   Babylon 5's first three seasons. Season 3's "The Swarm" was the first
>   episode to use Foundation's effects exclusively. Deep Space Nine
>   started using Foundation Imaging in conjunction with Digital Muse one
>   year later (season 6). In its later seasons, Voyager featured visual
>   effects from Foundation and Digital Muse.

[image: model of Voyager]

Comment: ...it was a dark time for the Federation =\

Comment: @22ndCenturyFza Every episode of Enterprise makes me feel like that.

Comment: @22ndCenturyFza: No, the dark time for the Federation was when Voyager came back.  For the Federation at large, that was a golden age - the Maquais, Janeway, 'Deadman' Kim, etc were all gone and no one had even *heard* of Neelix.